# How to create package installer link for Android application package?

Tags: android, package

i have created one Android Application.
I install it on mobile by connecting USB.
I want to install it without connecting mobile to PC.
How can I create package installer link to install pacakage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good walkthrough of sorts on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

FOR DEPLOYING:

Here are a few steps to get you started:

1. Right click on your Project and locate *"Android Tools"* at the bottom.
2. Locate an option in the sub-menu *Export Signed Application Package...*

In a Window that pops up:

1. **Select the project to export**: Ensure you have the same project selected that you wish to create an APK of and hit the *Next* button
2. **Keystore Selection**: You have the option of either choosing an existing keystore or creating a new one. Follow the steps based on the option you select.
3. **Key alias selection**: While creating a new Keystore, you also create an alias. Based on your earlier selection (in STEP 2), you will have to choose an existing key or create a new one. Again, follow the steps in this section.
4. Finally, **Destination and key/certificate checks**: Hit the *browse* button and select the path on your computer where you want the APK to be created.

After following these steps, you will have an APK created which can deployed to the Google Play store or can be transferred to any _ compatible_ devices for installation.

Comment: Hey Thanks, It worked fine. Now How can I deploy it on my mobile Device. I have Samsung galaxy android phone?

Comment: @Asmita: Glad to have helped. There are several ways of transferring your APK to a device. You could upload it to DropBox and email the link, or something simpler like connecting via USB and transferring to the SD-Card and then installing from a File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your Application apk(installer) from your project bin folder and store it in your phone memory or sdcard.
After copy in phone memory or sdcard. use file browser to find apk and install it via android default installer.

Thanks